Eliminar filas con celdas vacías
De un dataframe original de cuatro columnas (1ª columna, una colección de tuits; 2ª columna, su frecuencia de repetición expresada en números enteros; 3ª columna, frecuencia de repetición expresada en porcentajes, 4ª columna, los mismos tuits filtrados) he eliminado las cadenas "pfizer" y "pfizergate" en la última columna, como resultado de ello, algunas filas han quedado con celdas en blanco, que distorsionan el posterior gráfico de frecuencias que he realizado. He aplicado la siguiente línea de código para eliminar esas filas:
pfizer_filtrado <- pfizer %>%
filter(!is.na(Tuit2) & nchar(Tuit2) != 0)
que ha eliminado todas las filas señaladas menos dos, no consigo saber el motivo, no sé si alguien me podría echar una mano

Probablemente es porque tienes espacios en blanco que son contados como characteres. Para ayudarte mas concreto, puedes colocar una muestra de tus datos para reproducir el problema.

Tiene razón, le pongo capturas del dataframe

Disculpe, no pude ponerle la captura, pero el otro compañero que me ha respondido me ha dado la solución, muchísimas gracias de todos modos por su apoyo

Dado que no contamos con un ejemplo que replique tu problema, estas son las posibles alternativas que pienso podrían ayudarte:
pfizer_filtrado <- pfizer %>% 
  mutate(Tiut2 = trimws(Tuit2)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Tuit2) & nchar(Tuit2) != 0,
         !Tiut2 %in% c(" ",""))


Muchísimas gracias, ha solucionado el problema

@jonas considera votar y aceptar la respuesta para que quede marcada como solucionado. Me alegra haberle ayudado.

¿Y eso cómo se hace? he marcado que la respuesta ha sido útil

Clic en la marca de check junto a la respuesta
